# Is Octavian making a huge mistake [spoilers for First Lord's Fury]

Tags: codex-alera

At the end of First Lord's Fury, Octavian asks Alera (basically a manifestation of the spirits of the land) how to change the way furycrafting works.  Specifically, he asks for two changes:

1. That one be able to increase one's furycrafting strength via will and practice, instead of being strongly controlled by birth
2. That the other races of Carna -- Icemen, Marat, Canem -- be able to develop conscious crafting

I get point 1, this is a pretty decent egalitarian move.  But point two strikes me as ... counterproductive in a number of ways.  Furycrafting was one of humanity's key levelers against these other races which are stronger and longer-lived than humans.  I understand that he wants to make friends with the other peoples of Carna, but isn't this a bit much?

Especially the Canem; they can live for centuries, now they can increase their furycrafting strength over all that time.  Octavian may have created our new wolf-sorceror overlords here.

What am I overlooking here?  What is the benefit of point 2 besides weakening Alerans relative to other races?

Comment: The second is *also* a decent egalitarian move. Tavi may simply feel it fairer for *all* people - even non-human people - to have access to furycrafting.

Comment: But consider this: the Vord will return in 100 years, in greater numbers than before. For the sake of one’s own survival, would one rather have *more* or *fewer* furycrafters?

Comment: Further, will the other species be as willing to cooperate if humans keep their greatest weapons to themselves? By sharing furycrafting, perhaps Tavi will motivate the other residents of Carna to share their unique knowledge and talents. We know that this possible to some extent with the Marat. What the Icemen do is similar to watercrafting. And the techniques of the Canem can also likely be taught. If you want to take, you also have to give.

Comment: And finally, we can’t presume that there’s no upper limit to furycrafting skill. Even if one can improve through practice, there’s no guarantee that the Canem, say, can continue improving over centuries, as opposed to hitting a plateau.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Tavi's strategy is trying to create a stronger Alera.**  There are two components you should consider, the past, and the future -

- **Holding furycrafting for Aleran humans only did not keep Alera unified or strong.** The kingdom was already falling apart quite well with humans - specifically, certain families - having the reins of ultimate power.  The lack of change and lack of any dire threat once the bulk of the continent was secure let multiple High Lords ambitions fester until Kalare cracked the nation.  If that hadn't happened, Alera might have stood against the Vord without losing over half their cities and countless lives.  Tavi needs to redistribute the power of furycrafting, or the Aleran nation will simply repeat old patterns.
- **He needs Alerans to have enemies - in the Canim fashion - or they won't learn.**  Tavi's greatest strength is learning and adapting - and recruiting - his enemies.  It's something the Canim truly appreciate, an enemy that is strong enough to beat you but honors and respects you.  This is just what the Canim bring to the table of ideas - the Marat and Icemen have plenty to teach Alerans too.  What Tavi is doing is applying his method of learning to the entire nation.  Alerans under this new system will be working side-by-side - *and competing* - with races that will force humans to learn from them or be left behind.  Alerans need to relearn skill, like Tavi did, not just power... and now skill *is power*.

All of this is for the inevitable return of the Vord.  The Canea Vord will eventually come, and will have the resources of a much larger continent to draw from.  This is how Tavi has beaten every enemy bigger than him to date - endure, outhink, outmaneuver, conquer.  Learn and apply *every possible advantage*, even from your enemies.  He is just trying to apply the conditions that taught him this to his new alliance.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but it's this part that I wonder about:  "an enemy that is strong enough to beat you but honors and respects you".  The Alerans were at best a shaky match for the Canem even before the change.   
 Tavi even mentions that it was discipline & furycraft which leveled the playing field even partway.  I worry that if Canem have their superior strength, longer lives, **and** furycrafting available, they'll start seeing Alerans as less than equal.  Maybe even prey.  All that said, the "Let's not get eaten by the Vord" angle carries a lot of weight...  ;D

Comment: @user54373 - you're right, but that's honestly the point. Tavi is the only human gadara, because he was forced to go without power and learn to be badass from scratch. Tavi wants a *nation of badass* - aleran, canim, marat, and icemen, every asskicker he can make. Nothing will inspire badass like "that wolf over there will eat you if you don't get your shit up - and he can cook you with his brain". Also, don't presume alerans won't steal blood magic and animal bonding now that everyone's sharing.

Comment: that's a good point.  I can just see a Canem crafter threatening an Aleran... "I will use my furycraft to make you bleed, monkey!"  Guy replies: 
 "Are you *really* sure you want me to have fresh blood available?"  Great food for thought, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

## No—in fact, this move is both fair and exceedingly shrewd

First of all, it’s easy to see why someone would want to make such a move on purely egalitarian grounds. Why *not* grant the same opportunities to each species, to whatever extent possible? That very principle is the foundation of many modern societies. Tavi can’t make humans live as long as the Canim, but he can at least give everyone an even playing field as far as furycrafting is concerned.

Besides, I see no reason to conclude from the text that someone’s furycrafting can continue growing without bound for centuries. There’s probably still a limit; it’s just that now everyone can theoretically reach it.

Finally, I think it’s implied that, until the vord invasion, the Canim really did always have the numbers to conquer Alera, but simply didn’t do it due to internal reasons. Their continent was enormous and had huge cities. So what else is new, even if the Canim can become more powerful?

But there are certainly very practical reasons to support such a plan.

### Quid Pro Quo

Tavi believes that if the various races of Carna share what they know with each other, all will benefit. He believes that the Canim have something to give humans, as the Marat did.

> “I cannot say the same,” Alera responded. “For which I find myself…
>   somewhat grateful. It would be awkward.” She inhaled slowly, then
>   nodded. “Are you sure you wish to continue on the path you have
>   begun?”
>
> “Well. You say I introduced you to Kitai, without realizing it,
>   because of our bond. That’s why you can speak to her.”
>
> “Indeed.”
>
> “Then you should trust me. Interaction with the other Marat will be
>   just as rewarding, on some level. As it will with the Canim. And the
>   Icemen are already watercrafting, whether they realize it or not. It’s
>   hardly any change at all.”

He’s probably right, too: the Canim and Icemen have their own sorcery, which the humans can benefit from learning. As with trade in the real world, though some may suffer, and certainly some will benefit disproportionately, there’s generally a net benefit to both parties. And links with the Marat offer their own possibilities.

### Who wants to die?

The Vord are going to come to Alera. As Alera herself says:

> “You have a century and a half, by my estimation. Perhaps two. And
>   then the Canean vord queen will come for you.”
>
> Tavi nodded. “Then I’ll make us ready. Or get us part of the way
>   there, at least.”

The Canem vord queen won’t have the furycrafting prowess of her counterpart, but she’ll have numbers beyond anything Alera has seen before. The Canem continent and its resources were enormous.

When an existential threat is knocking on your door, do you want *more* furycrafters, or *fewer*? It’s what is colloquially called “a no-brainer.”

Besides, if the humans give *their* sorcery to the Canim and others, they buy goodwill, and (in keeping with the above points), are more likely to be granted the Canim and Icemen and Marat’s secrets.

And then everyone wins. Or at least doesn’t get assimilated by the vord. And honestly, that’s what they’re aiming for at this point.